# Difference between JBoss Fuse and Application server

Tags: java, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, application-server, apache-servicemix

I am currently using `Jboss Fuse 6.0`, I know what all features it povides e.g.

[Jboss Fuse Overview](http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse/overview/)

How it is different from Application server?

Since the topic is to large to explain I am looking for atleast the features provided by Application Server which are not available in JBoss Fuse and vise versa.

Answer (score 2):

Fuse is mainly targeted at implementing Integrations. So it is kind of a specialized Application server. It is not an JEE application server though

As Fuse is based on Apache Karaf (OSGi server) you can use all the features it provides too e.g JPA and transaction support. So you can use it similar to a JEE application server. The programming model is a bit different though.

Comment: Weblogic also provide integration and OSGi functionality. Any other Jboss feature which make it different from any other application server?

Comment: No idea about the Fuse specifics :-) I am rather one of the Apache Karaf people. What I like is that all the Apache projects are community driven. So you can influence the course of the project. Which is not the case for Weblogic.